# SQL creating new column names for similar table

Tags: mysql, create-table

I have a table called Person in which each column has the letters 'Person' as a prefix; i.e. PersonLastName, PersonAddress1,  PersonCity, etc.  I wish to create a new table with the same structure as Person but with a different prefix on the column names, such as XxxLastName, XxxAddress1, XxxCity.  If I use

```
Create Table Like Person
```

I will get the right structure, but the original column names from Person. Of course I can then rename all the columns, but that is a tedious job.  Is there a way to create a table like Person and simultaneously rename the columns according to some rule?

Comment: Please tell me why do you require having a prefix?

Comment: I think the table is prefix enough: `Person.FirstName` is equally (if not more meaningful) than `Person.PersonFirstName`

Comment: Ed,  Rob, There are numerous reasons why I use my own prefixes.  One of them is that I have an extensive table of meta-type data which is not captured by MySql and which I maintain myself.  I sometimes need to look things up based on the prefixes.  Another is ease of locating column names in my code when I am debugging.  A third is for my own internal clarity.  The database is very complex, and I don't want to get lost.

Comment: Ryan, back to you after I check out your idea.

Comment: Ryan, not clear how this would help.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that arbitrarily.  You can do it in 1 statement like the following, but I don't know if that will be any better for you than just doing alters after a simple CREATE TABLE LIKE query.

```
You could do:
CREATE TABLE Dog AS
  (SELECT PersonFirstName AS DogFirstName, PersonLastName AS DogLastName FROM Person);
```

Another way (obviously) would be to write a script in another language outside of SQL.

Another thing you can do is get the existing column names off the table

```
SELECT @colname := `COLUMN_NAME`  FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS`  WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='YOURDATABASE' AND `TABLE_NAME`='YOURTABLE' limit 0, 1;
```

Then using mysql substring() chop off the prefix.

```
set @chopped = substring(@colname, ....)
```

Then set another mysql variable to the new prefix.

```
set @newprefix = ''
```

Then run a CREATE TABLE AS query and concat the variables (new prefix + chopped column name).  This will get complicated quickly.

I think from others comments it's clear that you should not try to do this automatically within mysql.  Best done with a script that can run logic easier.

Comment: In what language would I write a script?